# PHP string comparison for strings which look the same in some views, but not in others

Tags: php, string, types, comparison

I have two strings that look the same when I echo them, but when I `var_dump()` them they are different string types:

Echo:

```
http://blah
http://blah
```

var dump:

```
string(14) "http://blah"
string(11) "http://blah"
```

strToHex:

```
%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%62%6c%61%68%00%00%00
%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%62%6c%61%68
```

When I compare them, they return false. How can I manipulate the string type, so that I can perform a comparison that returns true?

What is the difference between string 11 and string 14? I am sure there is a simple resolution, but I have not found anything yet. No matter how I implode, explode, UTF-8 encode, etc., they will not compare the strings or change type.

Comment: Do they compare if you `trim()` them both?

Comment: how do you get these variables, do you have some more code?

Comment: Is `blah` just an example, or the real output? Do you use other Unicode characters? Whitespace etc?

Comment: What I am doing is encrypting some data string1, with mcrypt. then as a control I am taking the encrypted data and decrypting it as string2, and comparing it with string1 to confirm that the encryption/decryption is correct. This is where string1 "blah" and string2 "blah" do not compare. They appear exactly the same when I echo them, but are different if I md5 them. There is no whitespace around the strings that I can see. Will try some more of these suggestions first.

Comment: Is string with those `"\x00"` at the end *before* or *after* crypting? If *after*, then those characters might be automatically added to the string so result after decrypting has some required length. If *before*, then crypting library might treat string as *null-terminated* string and stop at first `"\x00"` character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the strings before comparing. There are *escaped* characters, like \t and \n, which are not visible.

`$clean_str = trim($str);`

Comment: If the problem is only with `"\x00"` characters at the end of the string, I would suggest to use `rtrim($str, chr(0))`. This will ensure that only null-characters from the end of the string will be removed.

Answer (score 9):

Letter "a" can be written in another encoding.

For example: `blаh`. Here `a` is a [Cyrillic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cyrillic#Adjective) 'а'.

All of these letters are Cyrillic, but it looks like Latin: у, е, х, а, р, о, с

Comment: got any reference on why these are longer, curios for more information?

Comment: +1 because I have no other ideas. But in question author's example it doesn't seem that `a` is a cyrillic a.

Comment: @gar_onn because utf-8 is multi-byte encoding, each symbol can take more than 1 byte.

Answer (score 6):

When using `var_dump()`, then `string(14)` means that the value is a `string` that holds `14` bytes. So `string(11)` and `string(14)` are not different "types" of strings; they are just strings of different length.

I would use something like this to see what actually is inside those strings:

```
function strToHex($value, $prefix = '') {
    $result = '';
    $length = strlen($value);
    for ( $n = 0; $n < $length; $n++ ) {
        $result .= $prefix . sprintf('%02x', ord($value[$n]));
    }
    return $result;
}

echo strToHex("test\r\n", '%');
```

Output:

```
%74%65%73%74%0d%0a
```

This decodes as:

- %74 - t
- %65 - e
- %73 - s
- %74 - t
- %0d - \r (carriage return)
- %0a - \n (line feed)

---

Or, as pointed out [in comments by Karolis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663379/php-string-comparison#comment7878319_6663560), you can use the built-in function [`bin2hex()`](http://www.php.net/bin2hex):

```
echo bin2hex("test\r\n");
```

Output:

```
746573740d0a
```

Comment: just try to var_dump any variable with `\r\n` and you'll see why this suggestion is wrong.

Comment: Actually there is `bin2hex()` function, but the recommendation is good.

Comment: @OZ_ in any case this kind of debugging  will clearly answer all the questions.

Comment: @OZ_, could you explain why is this suggestion wrong? I know what `var_dump()` outputs, but I also know that author says that his strings are `"blah"` (no `\r`, no `\n`, no other characters). If he does not see anything more than just `"blah"`, it is worth examining what actually is in those strings, and that cannot be done with basic `echo` or `var_dump()`. Like @Karolis says, it will answer all the questions on why are those strings different.

Comment: @Karolis, I edited an answer to include `bin2hex()` - didn't know about that function.

Comment: @binaryLV I agree with @Karolis, this code will help to see the difference. But difference not in spaces, because this difference will be easy noticed in output of var_dump. +1 for useful code, anyway.

Comment: @OZ_, even if strings are different because of whitespaces, it still *might* show it. `var_dump($var)` does not wrap output in `<pre/>`, it also does not change `Content-Type` from `text/html` to `text/plain`, so both `var_dump("blah      ")` and `var_dump("blah   \t  \r \n")` *might* be displayed as `"blah "` (although author shows that output is without any space, we cannot know if that's the real output).

Comment: @binaryLV result of the strToHex posted above, you can see the problem  what are the three appended %00?

Comment: @paj, about appended %00 - there are `"\x00"` (or `chr(0)`) characters at the end of string. We can't tell how you get them, as you did not specify source of strings (i.e., where they come from). As for the "*`trim()` resolved the problem*" phrase - I believe it is just a workaround for a problem that lies somewhere else, where those `"\x00"` are appended...

Comment: @binaryLV the string originated from encrypted data I read from a file with fopen, decrypted with mcrypt and then compared to the original unencrypted plain text string. Could it be I read in the EOF data from the file? The data is only on the first line of the file so now I am reading just the first line in. Either way the extra characters did not effect the decrypt. I am happy now that I can encrypt, decrypt and control check my data ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try to [trim](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) these strings:

```
if (trim($string1) == trim($string2)) {
  // Do things
}
```

Comment: if this was the case, wouldent the var_dump show a space (at least one visibele) ?

Comment: as  @gar_onn says var_dump shows only 1 space char if there are consecutive space chars. anyway there's no other reason why the dump could say that the two strings have different length

Comment: but in the question there is no (not even 1) space char

Comment: the original question wasn't even formatted, that's why I suppose that he didn't considered the space

Comment: @OZ_ your answer can explain why the two strings are "different" in the content, but not in the length right?

Comment: @VAShhh not. Length will be different too.

Comment: @OZ_ my face is like ._. at the moment

Comment: @VAShhh well, maybe it will be interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding

Comment: @OZ_ my face was that way for the chosen answer... nevermind :|

Answer (score 1):

Probably Unicode strings within the upper range are counted as double bytes.

Use [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) to check lengths.

Also some characters may not be visible, but present (there are many of Unicode spaces, etc.)

Generally, when you work with Unicode functions, you should use the `mb_*` string functions.

You may overload string encoding functions in *[php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)* to always use `mb_*` functions instead the standard ones (I am not sure if [Xdebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) honors those settings).

In PHP 6 this problem will be solved, as it should be globally Unicode-aware.

Comment: it's correct way to find length, but in comparison strings will be always different. And they should be.