# PHP string comparison not working, file reading

Tags: php, string, comparison

I am using PHP to read in a tab delimited CSV file and a pipe delimited TXT file. Unfortunately, I cannot get a string comparsion to work even though the characters (appear) to be exactly the same. I used trim to make sure to clean up hidden characters and I even tried type-casting to string.

Var dump shows they are clearly different but I am not sure how to make them the same?

```
// read in CSV file
$fh = fopen($mapping_date, 'r');
$mapping_data = fread($fh, filesize($mapping_date));
... 
// use str_getcsv to put each line into an array
// get values out that I want to compare

$this_strategy = (string)trim($strategy_name);
$row_strategy = (string)trim($row3[_Strategy_Name]);

if($this_strategy == $row_strategy) { // do something }

var_dump($this_strategy);
```

Vardump: string(16) "Low Spend ($0.2)"

```
var_dump($row_strategy);
```

Vardump: string(31) "Low Spend ($0.2)"

Can't figure out for the life of me how to make this work.

Comment: I should add that I tried strcmp and also tried using inarray (as it is in an array originally) if(in_array ($row_strategy, $row1["Strategies"], false))

Comment: Are you using the same methods to open the CSV file as you are the TXT file?

Comment: The fact that the lengths are different might indicate a problem with string encoding. Print out each char of each string. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6663560/384155

Comment: Yes, using the same method (fopen and str_getcsv) but the two files being read are generated differently (which might be why the bytes are different).    here are the hex dumps, clearly different     String 1: %4c%6f%77%20%53%70%65%6e%64%20%28%24%30%2e%32%29     
String 2: %4c%00%6f%00%77%00%20%00%53%00%70%00%65%00%6e%00%64%00%20%00%28%00%24%00%30%00%2e%00%32%00%29

Comment: Looking through that hex looks like string 2 is being filled with %00 between each value. Any suggestions for how I clean that out?

Comment: Is it from some sort of database? What encoding is used in the database? How do you insert the data?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the database encoded in UCS2 (assuming it's MySQL). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-ucs2.html

You can use possibly use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert the format - but there's an example in the comments on that page (but it doesn't use iconv - http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#49171 ). I've not tested it.

Alternatively, change the database field encoding to utf8_generic or ASCII or whatever the file is encoded as?

---

Edit: Found the actual PHP function you want: [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding) - UCS2 is one of the supported encodings, so enable that in php ini and you're good to go.